# Push container to local, insecure registry as part of the pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, docker-registry

As part of my pipeline I have a step that builds a container and tries to push it to a local (insecure) registry. The agent is a local agent and it does have access to the local network.

The error I get is:

```
##[error]Get https://<local_host_name>.local:32000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

I did add an extra task that tries to add the correct docker settings entry for allowing insecure registry

```sh
echo '{  "insecure-registries" : ["<local_host_name>.local:32000"]}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

But that does not seem to have any effect. What would be the correct approach for that?

Comment: Anyone from Microsoft that could provide some pointers to this issue?